# Privoxy: Disable "deanimate-gifs" filter

Tags: debian, privoxy, traffic-filtering

I'm using privoxy on a debian server and want to disable the privoxy filter `deanimate-gifs`.

I found these instructions to disable it via the web-based toggle feature:

- Point web browser to http://config.privoxy.org/
- Click on View & change the current configuration
- Click on .\default.action Edit
- Find line that says Edit, Set to Cautious, Set to Medium, Set to Advanced & Click on Edit
- Search for deanimate-gifs
- Click on "Disable" radio button
- Locate and click on Submit

To use the web-based toggle feature one must have compiled Privoxy with support for this feature, which I have not.

So I just want to change this setting in a configuration file.

What file do I have to edit and what excatly do I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If found the answer:

The filters are set in the `.action` files. To disable the `deanimate-gifs` filter I searched for it in the `match-all.action` and the `default.action` and commented out the regarding lines.

For more information about the action files: http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html

Example for the `match-all.action`:

```
#############################################################################
# Id: match-all.action,v
#
# This file contains the actions that are applied to all requests and
# may be overruled later on by other actions files. Less experienced
# users should only edit this file through the actions file editor.
#
#############################################################################
{ \
+change-x-forwarded-for{block} \
# +deanimate-gifs{last} \
+filter{refresh-tags} \
+filter{img-reorder} \
+filter{banners-by-size} \
+filter{webbugs} \
+filter{jumping-windows} \
+filter{ie-exploits} \
+hide-from-header{block} \
+hide-referrer{conditional-block} \
+session-cookies-only \
+set-image-blocker{pattern} \
}
/ # Match all URLs
```